# Select most recent date and calculate avg of multiple values in different rows

Tags: sql, max, aggregate, average

i am building a query for a table that has several columns:

- name
- date
- about 10 columns with integer values

Now i want to return a table that returns one row for each unique element of the name column.
This row has three columns: name, date, and an average of the integer values columns.
The date is the most current date for this particular name element.
And the average value is the average of all integer values of this particular row.

```
SELECT name, Max(date), SUM(value1+value2+value3+value4...+value10)/10 
FROM myTable
WHERE *join statements*
Group by name
```

The problem with this is, that due to the face that sum aggregates all the values of the columns, the computed value is not the average of this single row.
Adding the values to the group by statement is not possible because the result should be displayed only by one row per name.

Hope the problem is clear. Any Ideas? Thanks!

---

**Edit:**
Thank you for your reply Gordon Linoff! The formulation of my problem was not that clear, sorry for that.

Actually there can exist entries with same name and date. Therefore I need to aggregate these entries, in case it is the most current date of this particular name element.

To clarify, here a possible table:

**|Name         |Date        |value1|value2|**

|Name   A  | 14/09/24   | 1    | 2    |

|Name   A  | 14/09/24   | 2    | 1    |

|Name   A  | 14/09/24   | 9    | 9    |

|Name   A  | 14/09/22   | 4    | 3    |

|Name   B  | 14/09/23   | 3    | 5    |

|Name   B  | 14/09/22   | 2    | 4    |

|Name   B  | 14/09/21   | 4    | 2    |

|Name   C  | 14/09/23   | 5    | 1    |

---

*The result shoud be:*

**|Name      |Date        |avg|**

|Name   A  | 14/09/24   | 4 |

|Name   B  | 14/09/23   | 4 |

|Name   C  | 14/09/23   | 3 |

With your hint, I think I found the right query for this problem, where 2 is the number of values per row:

```
SELECT name, max(date), avg(value1+value2)/2
FROM myTable t
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from myTable t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.date > t.date
                 )
group by name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually want an aggregate.  You want to choose the most recent row for each name.  Here is a method that uses `not exists`:

```
SELECT name, date, (value1+value2+value3+value4...+value10)/10 
FROM myTable t
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from myTable t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.date > t.date
                 );
```

Comment: @user2974776 . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?  I'm curious why.

Comment: I thought it would be more clear than becuase your answer did not solve the problem directly. Nevertheless, thanks a lot and of course I accept your answer because it was helpful!

Comment: @user2974776 . . . I only asked because you did not accept another answer (a typical reason for unaccepting).  As the author, you have full control.  You can edit either my answer, your question, or add another answer with the full solution to your problem.